# ReportViewer: Find Button is visible but greyed out

Tags: winforms, report-viewer2010

In ReportViewer, after a report loads the textbox associated with the Find button, the *Find* and *Next* buttons are always disabled. I have set `ShowFindControls` to true in designer and I am also setting it in code.

```
this.reportviewer.ShowFindControls = true
```

How do I enable it? It seems pretty straightforward but I am unable to figure it out. Searched  the forums but couldn't find a solution.

I am using Reportviewer (local report) , Winforms.

Comment: Have you tried it in Internet Explorer? I've noticed some things occasionally don't work in other browsers, such as the Print feature.

Answer (score 2):

I read some of your other report questions and you said you set your report's DisplayMode to PrintLayout by default. The Find/Next controls are not enabled and cannot be enabled in PrintLayout mode, you must be in Normal mode.